# Replace strings XSLT

Tags: xslt

i'm stucked. Please help me with a little problem.

I have to change just two specific lines in XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:PublishTP_WORKORDER xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" creationDateTime="2014-04-11T10:43:51+04:00" transLanguage="RU" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1397198631936413520" maximoVersion="7 5 20130829-1209 V7510--1" event="1">
  <TP_WORKORDERSet xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <WORKORDER action="Replace">
      <ACTCOST xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ACTFINISH xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ACTINTLABCOST>0.0</ACTINTLABCOST>
      <ACTINTLABHRS>0.0</ACTINTLABHRS>
      <ACTLABCOST>0.0</ACTLABCOST>
      <ACTLABHRS>0.0</ACTLABHRS>
      <ACTMATCOST>0.0</ACTMATCOST>
      <ACTOUTLABCOST>0.0</ACTOUTLABCOST>
      <ACTOUTLABHRS>0.0</ACTOUTLABHRS>
      <ACTSERVCOST>0.0</ACTSERVCOST>
      <ACTSTART>2013-11-08T12:03:26+04:00</ACTSTART>
      <ACTTOOLCOST>0.0</ACTTOOLCOST>
      <ADDRESS/>
      <AMCREW/>
      <AMS>0</AMS>
      <AOS>0</AOS>
...........................
      <WORKORDERID>10</WORKORDERID>
      <WORKPACKMTLSTATUS/>
      <WORKTYPE/>
      <WOSEQUENCE xsi:nil="true"/>
    </WORKORDER>
  </TP_WORKORDERSet>
</max:PublishTP_WORKORDER>
```

I need to replace "PublishTP_WORKORDER" with "Create_WORKORDER", both open and close tags.

It works fine with:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/max:PublishTP_WORKORDER">
  <xsl:element name="max:CreateTP_WORKORDER">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But in XML file it could be "PublishTP_WORKORDER2" or "PublishTP_WORKORDER3" and so on.
It should be changed to "CreateTP_WORKORDER2", "CreateTP_WORKORDER3" etc
And this XSLT scheme stops working. It's just doesn't recognize strings with added numeric symbols. How could i turn it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that your entire XML input? If so can you not just match on `/`?

Comment: Nope, enitre XML is big enough. I've tried to delete this "/", but the string is still "PublishTP_WORKORDER2"

Comment: Okay, can you update your xml example with a bit more XML? I think I know what you'd *like* to do but it's infinitely harder in XSLT as opposed to say php.

Comment: Instead of listing all the things you **cannot** rely upon being there, state the one thing that you know for sure you can hang onto. As an aside, XSLT is a custom job; if the source XML is constantly changing, then eventually the fixed XSLT is going to become obsolete.

Comment: Updated. In the XML body just list of attributes. It works okay, but only if there's no other chars after or before "max:PublishTP_WORKORDER", but it could be

Comment: "max:PublishTP_WORKORDER" is a fixed tag for sure. The only thing that could be changed is an index at the end like ...WORKORDER2 or WORKORDER15.

Comment: Will it always be the root element?

Comment: Yes. It's always root element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's always root element

Then how about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="substring-after(local-name(), 'PublishTP_WORKORDER')" />
    <xsl:element name="max:CreateTP_WORKORDER{$suffix}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```